# Find a file with a pattern using find command

Tags: bash, find

I have three types of files

- Files having XXXYYY.A[1-9][0-9]*B; example: `ABC.A10B`
- Files having XXXYYY_random.A[2-9][0-9]*B; example: `ABC_random.A2B`
- Files having XXXYY_test.A[1-9][0-9]*B; example: `ABC_test.A14B`

I want to find all the type 1 and type 2 files. I need only `XXXYYY_test.A1B` of type 3

I wrote the following bash command to do that

`find . -name "*.A[1-9]*B" ! -name "*_test.A[2-9][0-9]*B"`

But the above command prints all the `*_test.A[0-9]*B` files.

What is the correct way to print type 1,2 and only `*_test.A1B` of type 3 in bash

Answer (score 0):

If you have gnu version of `find` then you can use `find` like this:

```
find . -regextype posix-extended -type f -regex '.*\.A[1-9][0-9]*B$'
```

IF YOU'RE ON OSX then use:

```
find -E . -type f -regex '.*\.A[1-9][0-9]*B$'
```